# AChartEngine - How to prevent label auto generation when graph gets zoom in or out in AChartEngine Android

Tags: android, achartengine

I am using AChartEngine Library to build chart in my application.

I am facing one issue with my TimeChart that when graph gets zoom in or out the lable gets generated again, I want to prevent that label generation when graph gets zoom in or out.

## Example :

TimeChart :

When I first prepare my graph it is showing 31 days but when I do the zoom out then some dates gets duplicated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this method and see if it improves things:

```
renderer.setXRoundedLabels(false);
```